# how to Validate Text boxes before submitting using javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have 2 text boxes with default value 0 and a submit button.Before submitting I am calling the following javascript function `onSubmit="return(validate_myfrm());`".I am not able to validate `text_1` with value 0.But for `text_2` the default value 0 is validated.

```
function validate_myfrm()
{

   var ans;
   if(document.myfrm.txt_1.value=="" ||document.myfrm.txt_1.value==0)
      {
              ans=confirm("Do you still want to continue with value 0 for text 1?");
              if(ans== true)
                  {
                     document.myfrm.txt_1.value=0;
                     document.myfrm.txt_2.focus();
                  }
              else
                  {
                     document.myfrm.txt_1.focus();
                  }
                 return false;
    }

   if(document.myfrm.txt_2.value=="" ||document.myfrm.txt_2.value==0)
            {
                ans=confirm("Do you still want to continue with value 0 for text 2?");
                if(ans== true)
                  {
                     document.myfrm.txt_2.value="0";
                     return true;
                  }
              else
                  {
                       document.myfrm.txt_2.focus();
                  }
                  return false;
            }
     return true;
```

}

If i return true; after `document.myfrm.txt_2.focus();` the page is redirected to next page without confirming the values for txt_2.Pls help

Answer (score 0):

document.myfrm.txt_bb1.value==0

should be: document.myfrm.txt_1.value==0

also:

Upon setting a return, the function will end and return the false or true set out in your function.

the first if when values are "" or 0 according your condition will always return false. since it is returning false, the function will end and return false.

edit:

here a simple validation example:

```
<form id="myfrm" name="myfrm" onSubmit="return(validate_myfrm());">
    <input type="text" name="txt_1" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="txt_2" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<span id="result"></span>

<script>

function validate_myfrm()
{
   if(document.myfrm.txt_1.value!="" && document.myfrm.txt_2.value!="")
   {
       return true;    
   } else {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Error fields cannot be empty";
       return false;
   }
}
</script>
```

remember in this, that whenever you use return in a function, it will stop the function and return the value set.

Answer (score 0):

your first condition should be like this

```
if(document.myfrm.txt_1.value=="" ||document.myfrm.txt_1.value==0)
 {

 }
```

Comment: @The-Val.. I am not getting you exactly..Should i leave blank after 1st condition??

Comment: No, it was just pointing out you to set proper variable name as Marc mentioned earlier but i didn't see it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Else If Instaed of if function now it will validate before submission.

```
 function validate_myfrm()
{

   var ans;
   if(document.myfrm.txt_1.value=="" ||document.myfrm.txt_1.value==0)
      {
              ans=confirm("Do you still want to continue with value 0 for text 1?");
              if(ans== true)
                  {
                     document.myfrm.txt_1.value=0;
                     document.myfrm.txt_2.focus();
                  }
              else
                  {
                     document.myfrm.txt_1.focus();
                     return false;
                  }
    }else if(document.myfrm.txt_2.value=="" ||document.myfrm.txt_2.value==0)
            {
                ans=confirm("Do you still want to continue with value 0 for text 2?");
                if(ans== true)
                  {
                     document.myfrm.txt_2.value="0";
                     return true;
                  }
              else
                  {
                       document.myfrm.txt_2.focus();
                  }
                  return false;
            }
     return true;
    }
}
```